# vue3 graphql composition api dynamic router not working

Tags: vue.js

**Hi, any ideas about the code below? Thank you.**

*My Idea is to create a list of blogs using vue3 graphql composition api (django backend). Fetching and creating new blog works fine. However, I have some problem on creating router-link for the detail of the blog. I followed the the example provided on vue apollo page, it didn't help.*

```js
<template>
{{blog.title}}
</template>

<script>
import { useQuery, useResult } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const BLOG = gql`
      query($id: Int!){
      blog(id: $id){
        id
        title
      }
}`
export default {
 props: [ 'id' ],
 
 setup(props) {
   const {result, error} = useQuery(BLOG, props)

const blog = useResult(result, null, data => data.allBlogs)
   return {blog, error }
 }

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

*console error is: *
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt4rZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed 'id' to 'blogId' and now it works fine.

```js
 setup(props){
        const {result, error, loading, refetch} = useQuery(gql`
            query getBlogById($blogId: ID!){
                blog(blogId: $blogId){
                    id,
                    title,
                    author,
                    body,
                    dataPublished
                }
            }
        `, () => ({
            blogId: props.blogId,
        }))

        const blog = useResult(result, null, data => data.blog)

        return { blog, error, loading, refetch}
    }
```